# How to check if number exists in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure and I have to modify it so it does not accept an empty string nor a null.

I currently have this as part of the stored procedure

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.tblUserCode WHERE iUserID = @UserID)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.tblUserCode (iUserID, sCode) 
    VALUES (@UserID, @Unlock)
END
```

However I don't want to enter anything into the table if the value is a null or string. The table only has user ids that have a code. It is currently storing 0s and empty strings when a user gets created and they leave the slot blank. I know it's this line because my access code checks if the code is 4 digits long and if it is only digits but when it returns a string that gets stored into the table.

Comment: Don't allow the procedure to run. Expand Access code that checks for 4 digits.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using MS SQL Server (not clear from your tags) as your DBMS. In that case:

```
NOT ISNULL(sCode,'')=''
```

Will check if sCode is not Null or an empty string. Add it to your `IF` statement.